# Why does this class return length 33 while that is not is not true?

Tags: c++

Currently I'm learning about classes and constructors. Yesterday I uploaded almost the same code, but with a different question. I needed to know something about delegation.

In my code 2 really strange things happen. In the main block I create object x that is part of the container class. When I try to output the lenght I get as ouput 33, which is ofcourse not true or at least not intended.

Maybe I should start another post for this, but it might be highly related. I also wrote in the main:

```
Container x1 = x;
std::cout << x1.GetData()[2] << std::endl;
std::cout << x1.GetLenght() << std::endl;
```

I tried to make a deep copy of x to x1. When I do .GetData() it shows really really small values (I think machine error) so that would indicate that the copy failed, but when I try to get the length the initial wrong output of 33.

This may be a bit messy, but due to covid I'm not able to ask the course instructors. Any feedback or material to think about would be highly appreciated.

Questions:

- Why do I get as output that the length of object x (and indirect x1)is 33 ?
- Why did the deepcopy fail to copy the elements?

  Code:

Class:

```
class Container
{
public: //[DO NOT MODIFY/REMOVE THESE GETTERS AND SETTERS: THEY ARE USED IN THE SPECTEST]
int GetLength() const {return length;}
double* GetData() const {return data;}
void SetLength(const int length) {this->length = length;}
void SetData(double* data) {this->data = data;}

public:
    // constructors
    Container(){
        length = 0;
        data = nullptr;
    }

Container(int len){
    int length = len;
    data = new double[length];
}

Container(std::initializer_list<double> il): Container(il.size())
{
    std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), data);
}

Container(const Container& other) : Container(other.length)
{
    for (auto i=0; i<other.length; i++){
        data[i] = other.data[i];
    }
}




// destructor
  ~Container()
   {
       delete[] data;
       length = 0;
       }
 


// operators
void print(const std::string& info) const
{
    // print the address of this instance, the attributes `length` and
    // `data` and the `info` string
    std::cout << "  " << this << " " << length << " " << data << "  "
        << info << std::endl;
}

private:
    int length;
    double* data;
};
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    Container x({1,2,4,5});
    std::cout << "x has address " << &x << std::endl;

    Container x1 = x;

    std::cout << x1.GetData()[2] << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: If you look **properly** at the two constructors you have written you will see that there is a very significant difference between them. This difference explains the strange results you are getting. Looking at your own code and seeing what you actually wrote instead of what you think you wrote is an important skill to have.

Answer (score 3):

`int length = len;` doesn't modify member but creates a local variable. it should simply be:

```
length = len;
```

or better, use initializer list:

```
Container(int len) :
    length{len}, 
    data{new double[length]}
{
}
```

Comment: Compilers should warn about such things. Of course most beginners would then ignore the warnings. Conventions such as prefixing every member variable with `m_` (or something) are a good idea IMO.

Comment: @john Compiler does warn about such things if you ask. `-Wshadow`